# Syntax Error in SQL Code, Login Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a login stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `Login` (in var_login INT, in var_username varchar(45), in var_password varchar(45), out var_role INT)
BEGIN
        declare var_user_role ENUM('PersonaleAmministrativo', 'PersonaleSegreteria', 'Insegnanti', 'Allievo');
        select `Ruolo`
            from User
            where `Username` = var_username
            and `Password` = md5(var_password);
            insert into var_user_role
        if var_user_role = 'PersonaleAmministrativo' then 
                set var_role = 1;
        elseif var_user_role = 'PersonaleSegreteria' then 
                set var_role = 2;
        elseif var_user_role = 'Insegnanti' then
                set var_role = 3;
        elseif var_user_role = 'Allievo' then 
                set var_role = 4;
        else 
                set var_role = 5;
        end if;
END

CREATE PROCEDURE `Login` (in var_login INT, in var_username varchar(45), in var_password varchar(45), out var_role INT)
BEGIN
        declare var_user_role ENUM('PersonaleAmministrativo', 'PersonaleSegreteria', 'Insegnanti', 'Allievo');
        select `Ruolo`
            from User
            where `Username` = var_username
            and `Password` = md5(var_password);
            insert into var_user_role
        if var_user_role = 'PersonaleAmministrativo' then 
                set var_role = 1;
        elseif var_user_role = 'PersonaleSegreteria' then 
                set var_role = 2;
        elseif var_user_role = 'Insegnanti' then
                set var_role = 3;
        elseif var_user_role = 'Allievo' then 
                set var_role = 4;
        else 
                set var_role = 5;
        end if;
END
```

but on line 9, it always get me an error

> "if is not valid at this position, expecting PARTITION, SET, SELECT,
> TABLE, VALUES"

pls help

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: That is NOT tsql / SQL Server. Tag correctly.

Comment: You should not give parameters and columns the same name (var_role) and this kind of if statement(flow control) is not appropriate try case instead.

Comment: @P.Salmon thx! i'm trying it right now!

Comment: @jarlh i'm using MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a flow control statement (if..end if) in an Insert as an alternative and assuming your table has 1 column (which your code implies)
Example of how to use case in insert (with select)

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(role varchar(20));

set @var_role = 1;

insert into t
select 
 case when @var_role = 1 then  
    'abs'
 else 'bbb'
 end 
;

select * from t;

+------+
| role |
+------+
| abs  |
+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```